# View background color ignored

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this (part of a) layout:

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.8">
    <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/paint_board_container" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <View android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

The background color of the innermost view is set to white, but I can't see it on the screen, even if its layout width is also set to fill_parent. Where is the problem?
Thanks.

Updated layout:

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="0dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.8" android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:background="#00FF00">
    <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/paint_board_container" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:background="#FF0000">
        <View android:layout_width="2000dip" android:layout_height="1000dip"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>
            <!-- android:minWidth="100dip" android:minHeight="100dip"/> -->
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Now I see the vertical scroll view, but not the horizontal one, even though the innermost view's width is set to 2000dip. How do I make the horizontal scroll view show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `View` by default has width and height of 0. Since the `HorizontalScrollView` has a height of `wrap_content`, it will set its height to 0 as well. Give the inner view a non-zero minimum width and height and you should see some white on the screen.

Comment: I set all the attributes to fill_parent, and still see nothing.

Comment: @user940016 - As an experiment, add these attributes to the `View`: `android:minWidth="100dp" android:minHeight="100dp"`. Also, give the scroll views a colored background so you can see where they are. Alternatively (and better), use the [Hierarchy Viewer tool](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html) to inspect your layout while it is on display.

Comment: Ok, so when I set the minimum height of the view, the horizontal scroll view resizes to that height, but how can I make it occupy all of the (vertical) scroll view?

Comment: @user940016 - Try adding `android:fillViewport="true"` as an attribute to the vertical scroll view (and the horizontal one, if that's what you want).

Comment: Ok, now the vertical scroll view is working fine, but I can't see the horizontal scroll view, even though I set the layout width of the innermost view to 2000dip.

Comment: @user940016 - please edit your question and post the latest version of your layout